# Deserialize XML with different tree structure for same node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-parsing

### Problem

I am working with XML structured like below, and I am having issues because the `<value>` tag can contain several types of data, and can sometimes have a nested value.  I have tried using an abstract class for `ListItem` and having value be several different types but it doesn't seem to work as XmlSerializer requires me to slap it with some way to select between the different sealed classes - which I cannot do.

```xml
<listContainer>
    <listItem>
        <value>
            <boolean>true</boolean>
        </value>
    </listItem>
    <listItem>
        <value>1</value>
    </listItem>
    <listItem>
        <value>HAI IM A STRING!</value>
    </listItem>
</listContainer>
```

### Additional notes

1. I also tried write a XmlReaderReader (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2abc1zd(v=vs.71).aspx) to try to drilldown into the nested tag if possible but that doesn't seem to a viable solution.
2. I cannot change the format of the XML, it comes from a third party feed.
3. The XML file is on the order of several gigs.  I am using a BufferedStream and the forward-only XmlReader passed to the default XmlSerializer to do the reading/deserialization for performance reasons.
4. This isn't root-level XML, it's nested within several other nodes, but I only need advice on how to serialize this correctly.

### code

```cs
public class listContainer {
    [XmlArray(ElementName="listItem")]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type=typeof(listItem), ElementName="listItem")]
    public List<listItem> listItem { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class listItem {
    // ... help ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xml schema contains ambiguity - in your example, HAI... and 1 can either both be of the same type, string, or 1 can be deserialized as integer.

I think there is no simple way to express these implicit rules as a serializable object, so I suggest to deserialize as XmlNode, and then do manual recognition based on node properties. For example, if XmlNode contains single nested  tag - deserialize as bool, if no tags - try to parse as int, otherwise use string, etc. The sample is very small, so its hard to tell if there will be many rules.

I had to modify sample, to include one more root level above, to deserialize properly. But you say this xml is already nested, so this should be ok.

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class container {
  [XmlArray("listContainer")]
  public List<listItem> listItem;
}

public class listItem {
    public XmlNode value;
}

class App {
  static void Main() {
    StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(@"sample.xml");
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(container));
    var result = serializer.Deserialize(fs) as container;  
    foreach (var res in result.listItem)
      Console.WriteLine(res.value.OuterXml);
  }
}
```

sample.xml:

```
<root>
<listContainer>
    <listItem><value><boolean>true</boolean></value></listItem>
    <listItem><value>1</value></listItem>
    <listItem><value>HAI IM A STRING!</value></listItem>
</listContainer>
</root>
```